# VB.Net parser to remove all "On Error" handlers

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I'm converting an old VB.Net project with a lot of useless error handlers.

I'd like to remove (or better comment out) all of such code:

- "On Error Resume Next" statements
- "On Error Goto XXX" statements
- "XXX :" labels and following line codes before the end of the procedure

With some more subtleties (eg. remove all "On Error Resume Next" but keep legacy Ony Error Goto" only within functions whose return value is Boolean)

I could probably handle the code as text using awk or perl, is there any existing tool more specific to handle .Net code ?

I'm using VS 2012 with .Net framework 4.5, the assembly compilation succeeds.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the code base size, but can't you simply do a search on all files for the above keywords and for each hit you take the action you see fit in that situation?

Comment: Regular Expressions and Find/Replace could do it... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself: Roslyn is perfect for this task.

Install the Roslyn SDK (requires VS 2013):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn

A good example is the method DeleteAssignmentStatementsFromASyntaxTree in \Roslyn SDK Preview\Samples\CSharp\APISampleUnitTests\FAQ.cs